# Retrocomputing golf

Tags: discussion, scope

I really quite like the [Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) challenges on Stack Exchange, but most of my answers to date have been for the Commodore 64 as I live in a PHP world and like the escapism/limitations of certain dialects of BASIC.

Would it be acceptable to set up similar challenges here? This could include one-liners as well.

Answer (score 17):

### No.

As much as I like [Programming Puzzles and Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/), this site is not the place to ask such questions. They are not a Q&A site, and we are, which is a big indication that the scopes are different.

Your proposed challenges would be on-topic for PPCG. If you write it well enough, you can only accept answers from languages that were created within a certain time-frame, which would have a similar effect to asking here (if such things were allowed).

Comment: As I'm unable to talk about the retro computing that interests me here (unless I have a specific question, or know an answer to someone else's question), I'd encourage some of the people here to give the Code Golf a go for their favourite old computers.

Comment: @ShaunBebbers You can always take it to [chat], or write something for the [meta-tag:blog].

Comment: I would agree with this but suggest something further.  Some sites, like Genealogy, hold a monthly chat challenge.  You could try suggesting such a challenge in our chat to see how it goes.  I'm not sure if it would be successful but it may be worth a try.

Comment: @Chenmunka That sounds like a good answer, or perhaps a further meta question ([chat] isn't active enough at the moment to be asked things).

Comment: @wizzwizz4:  I thought that, if it goes well, it could perk up our chat room a bit.  I'm not sure we're up to the standards of http://meta.genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/1898/2663 yet but we can see.